# Externally Rated - CAT Cables - how to tell

Tags: layer1, cabling, cable, utp

How can you tell a CAT6 cable is externally rated? It is a requirement for a project I'm working on.

Many thanks,
Vlad

Comment: "externally rated"??? Direct burial? Areal? Fresh or Salt water submersible?  If it's not etched onto the cable and/or printed on the box/spool, then it doesn't do it.

Comment: I assume it's areal.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No common usage cable is rated for exposure to the natural elements. If it isn't going to be used inside of a home or environment-controlled switching office, it either needs to be specially ordered, or carried inside of conduit which is tailored to the task. Not to say that it won't work, but rather that it isn't designed to perform under that duress. Even a small amount of water can attenuate a signal if it somehow finds its way into the core, and there are numerous ways in which the cladding of a non-hardened cable can be breached.

Short answer: If it looks like the stuff you would plug into your home device, don't use it outside. It needs to be protected.

Comment: Hi James, do you have any references for the statement about water on the outside of the cable causing attenuation?  [This company's website](http://www.cat-5-cable-company.com/faq-bury-burial-cat-5-cable.html) seems to indicate that typical cat5 can survive the elements with no major concerns.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the feedback! It is definitely indicated that there are cases in which individuals have buried their cat-5, unshielded, outside of a conduit, with no ill effect. Unfortunately, that isn't guaranteed, because the cable is not manufactured to withstand that level of duress.

Comment: @Mike The fact of the matter is that it all depends on local weather and wildlife. If you live in an even-tempered area, free of seismic activity, with little to no vermin, you would potentially be able to see the cable perform fine. Humidity, extreme (hot or cold) weather, wildlife, and shifting terrain can cause serious issues. Any combination of weather could compromise the integrity of the non-guaranteed sheathing. At short distances, you might even be fine at that point, but not in the long-term, and definitely not for long-distance runs.

Comment: Thus far neither of the comments above respond to my question in the comments about signal attenuation

Comment: @Mike I appreciate that you're looking for more concrete evidence, but I'd be hard-pressed to obtain any real figures measuring dB loss or noise experienced on lines in various weather cases. That being said, having the cladding sitting directly in water isn't necessarily the problem so much as the other potential factors in an unprotected, outdoors installation. Any amount of moisture on bare copper will cause corrosion. It doesn't take many alternating hot and cold days or squirrels chewing the cable to allow moisture to saturate the core of the twisted pairs.

Comment: @Mike Ambient static electricity also has the potential for affecting the signal strength in a dry weather environment. The dry weather environment would probably have a tendency towards harsh sunlight; combined with the dryness, this would crack the non-reinforced plastic cladding, which would cause interference between the various twisted pairs.

Comment: @Mike Non-hardened, non-guaranteed cable that is developed for home use and not for outdoor use does not adhere to the same QC standards that the hardened and reinforced cable would. The cladding is thin and imperfect, and it is possible to encounter microscopic holes in which moisture could enter. Again, I must say that it is possible to have a common-usage cable used in an outdoors installation with no issue, but that is not what it is designed for.

Comment: James, I could consider removing my downvote if you can improve your answer to include facts based on evidence, which you link to in your answer.  As it stands, the answer claims that "Even a small amount of water on the outside of a cable's cladding can attenuate the signal strength."; however, we have found no factual basis for that statement.

Comment: @Mike Re-reading my answer, I can see how it could be misleading. I have removed the statement about water on the outside of the cabling causing attenuation, as there is no hard evidence to that effect.